# Kafka producer & consumer sync process

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want delete 10 items so I send 10 items to topic of kafka, my idea is that when producer send 10 items to kafka and it reponse ack, I return status 200 to client. But it has a problem if consumer just consumes 8 items and item 9 is failed, so user will still see 2 items fail and this is wrong logic. But I just know that producer sent successfully or not and don't know consumer consume all items success or not. How can I resolve this problem?

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct approach? Kafka consumers should not block for HTTP status code responses since HTTP clients/server have their own timeouts, separate from Kafka's.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. This is my idea. but in my idea when producer send message to topic and broker send ack to producer, I will return HTTP 200 to client, not mention about consumer in this process.

Comment: I would recommend 201, 202 or 204 code rather than 200, in general, for a producer. But yes, this has no interaction with a consumer, and wasn't what my comment was about... But there is also no guarantee you'll get an ack before the http client/server request times out (what if the broker is down/slow)? Note: There already exists a Kafka REST Proxy project - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html#produce-and-consume-json-messages

Comment: What should I do in this case? You said that the client can timeout before I send a response so how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm saying don't do request-reply... You simply wouldn't block for longer than necessary. HTTP streaming responses can be done, such as websockets or server sent events. Or you could not add a consumer in an HTTP request at all. Instead, run on a background thread, writing to some database, then your HTTP get function would instead query that, not read anything directly from Kafka, returning 404 or 200, accordingly for eventual consistency (again, no guarantee the consumer has seen any event)